# C# System.Collections.Generic cannot use GetValueOrDefault method

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I'm following a tutorial on handling textbox validation, step by step. However, I keep receiving an error "Dictionary<string, List> does not contain a definition for 'GetValueOrDefault'...", even though is certainly works in the video I'm watching.

I'm using System.Collections.Generic, implementing INotifyDataErrorInfo. I have the following property:

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, List<string>> _propertyErrors = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

I have the following method:

```
public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
{
    return _propertyErrors.GetValueOrDefault(propertyName, null);
}
```

But it will not accept that I'm trying to use GetValueOrDefault. Why is that? All my research shows it is available.

Comment: I'm sure your video is amazing, but `GetValueOrDefault` is for nullables not dictionaries. Unclear what you are trying to do, perhaps `TryGetValue`?

Comment: If you have a concern about a video you're watching, your question needs to be directed at the author of the video. There is no way to ask the question here and have it meet the requirements of the site, especially the expectation that the question will remain relevant indefinitely, which is certainly not the case for the above.

Comment: You might be using the wrong .Net version. It's not available in .Net 4.8 and older. It was added to .Net Core 2.0+, .Net Standard 2.1 and .Net 5.0+: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.collectionextensions.getvalueordefault?view=net-5.0

Comment: Absolutely irrelevant to the question, but based on your (current) username, I believe sincere congratulations are in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there's some misunderstanding but `TryGetValue` is the thing that you need.

```cs
public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName) 
{
    return _propertyErrors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out var value) ? value : null; // 'null' will be hit here if there's no requested key in the Dictionary
}
```

---

Btw,

```cs
private readonly Dictionary<string, List<string>> _propertyErrors = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

isn't a Property but a Field.

Here's a Property (for example):

```cs
public Dictionary<string, List<string>> PropertyErrors { get; } = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

Comment: Thanks aepot! I appreciate the correction, too, on my terminology. I'm trying hard to learn this and appreciate thoughtful answers whereas a lot of people downvote or seem to criticize.

Answer (score 1):

If Dictionary.GetValueOrDefault is giving you compile errors, it's probably because you are on a older version of .Net and the examples you are pulling from are on a newer version of .Net.

As others have stated, TryGetValue is most likely what you want and should be a suitable replacement for the missing GetValueOrDefault.

If you absolutely must have .GetValueOrDefault, you will need to upgrade your project to .Net Core 2.0, .Net Standard 2.1, or .Net 5.0.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.collectionextensions.getvalueordefault?view=net-5.0

If you scroll down you will see a big section that says "Applies to" and "> .Net 6.0 preview 3 and other versions". If you click the arrow, it will expand and show the other versions this function exists in.